VS Code Extension: Save Functionality Not Working
This is my first ever VS Code extension; and most of this code is auto-generated.
I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension in TypeScript that allows users to edit SQL insert statements in a table view and save the changes back to the original document. However, I'm encountering an issue where the save functionality is not working as expected.
While debugging, the code doesn't seem to reach inside the saveDisposable block. How can I debug it further?
code:
https://github.com/niqbal/dml_view/blob/main/src/extension.ts
EDIT:
So i have noticed that the save request reaches my code , when i do command+S on the sql file view; but not when I Save in the table view; How can i make it work in the table view?
